# How to use NHaml in MVC 4?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, haml, nhaml

I have used haml in Ruby on Rails, and I found a haml version in .Net called NHaml, I am tired to search how to implement NHaml in a web application, I read this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/asp-net-mvc-tip-35-use-the-nhaml-view-engine but I can't complete the steps because I have an error with this line

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NHamlControllerFactory());
```

I think that the tutorial is for a old version, I need to use Html in MVC 4, really I don't know if the project is dead, because the information that I found is of 2011, 2010, 2009...

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: "can not find the type or namespace name of NHamlControllerFactory"

Comment: NHaml links: https://github.com/NHaml/NHaml   https://code.google.com/p/nhaml/

Comment: Generally speaking, NHaml is dead, or at best a deadman walking in terms of updates. Getting it running for MVC 4 would basically be all on you to edit it. You're probably better off getting use to Razor syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove any old versions you have and install this one:

https://github.com/NHaml/NHaml

Then, add this line:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new NHaml.Web.Mvc3.NHamlMvcViewEngine())
```

Comment: Instead of downloading from GitHub, you could also install the [System.Web.NHaml.Mvc3 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.NHaml.Mvc3/).